# GraphQL vs REST frontend/backend balance of work

Tags: ios, graphql

I've always worked on iOS development (Swift) with REST services, but I recently started working on a project that uses GraphQL.
The point is, that I feel that much of the work that was previously done by the BE, it's done by me now.

As an example, this situation I'm facing now.

Our app handles customers that interact with services (one active service per customer).
I only need to know the active service to show it, but the endpoint I was given returns all services (expired ones and current) of one client, and I was told I should check if they are active or not.
For doing that, I need to map all services, parse an extra layer on the object to get the expiration time, convert the time string and compare it to now() to see if it's active (this is how data is structured on the schema)

With REST, I would have received the active service on the endpoint and that's all.

**My question is**: is this how really GraphQL should work, or it's just that the BE team is somewhat lazy and is making the FE team do part of their work? My problem is that I don't really know how GraphQL should work on the BE, so I can't really defend my position there.

This was a little example, but I'm facing these situations everyday and I feel that most of my time I'm doing "table comparison" work instead of FE things.

Comment: There's nothing intrinsic to either technology that would make it work this way.  I could easily imagine swapping the technologies – in GraphQL you could hypothetically make a query `activeService { ... }`, but you're being moved on to a REST API that only provided a `/services` GET call that you have to parse out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's give you some ammo to work with your back-end team.

In your situation you have a schema that probably looks like:

```
Query {
  getServices(customerId: ID!) [Services]
  … more queries
}
```

You give the `getServices` query a `customerId` and you get back all their services, active or not.

Behind the scenes the back end team has done some incredibly complex code to *resolve* this query, something like:

```
getServices: (_,{ customerID },context) => database('services')
  .where({customerId))
  .select();
```

> it can literally be that simple assuming an ORM talking to an RDB. Handling identity and access management (IAM - does the requester have the right to access this data?) may add some overhead but not a lot.

What you need is:

```
Query {
  getServices(customerId: ID!) [Services]
  getActiveServices(customerId: ID!) [Services]
  … more queries
}
```

and an extra *resolver*:

```
getActiveServices: (_,{ customerID },context) => database('services')
  .where({customerId))
  .andWhere({status: 'active'})
  .select();
```

If you have access to the back-end repo make the change yourself, file a pull-request and update your cv to say *full-stack developer*.

Answer (score 1):

> is this how really GraphQL should work, or it's just that the BE team is somewhat lazy and is making the FE team do part of their work? My problem is that I don't really know how GraphQL should work on the BE, so I can't really defend my position there.

As pointed out this in the comment, this isn't really about GraphQL vs Rest, it's just badly designed api at least with the information given. One of the major benefits of GraphQL is that you can get fetch the data you need in one query **and** fetching only the data you need. So the api is definitely not well designed if it forces you to overfetch data. When the GraphQL api is well designed, it should make your job a lot easier since you don't have to do chained REST queries but can instead write one query to get exactly what you want.

It'd probably be best to either have `activeService` field or have some kind of filter for getting only active services, in case it's technically possible that multiple services are active. Obviously I don't have all the information about the api etc so I had to make some assumptions.

Even though we don't have the details I'll have to point out that it seems possible they are using some technology like [hasura](https://hasura.io/) which will automatically generate GraphQL api from database schema. That would explain why the api seems clunky and you feel like you're doing lot of "table comparison". Because it's possible that it's simply db state exposed in fancy api with no business logic in between. I'm not saying that you couldn't make a good api with Hasura. It'd require mork work than just autogenerating the whole api though.